# ndiswrapper driver problem

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, broadcom

I'm trying to solve my wifi problem by installing the driver, for that i think i should install the windows driver using ndiswrapper, the problem is when i want to install the driver using this software, i should select an .inf file that i should find in the extracted files of the .exe driver, so the problem is i don't find the .inf file in the extracted package.

I tried a lot of another Lenovo drivers (audio and video drivers) and i always don't find the .inf file, BUT when i try for example a HP driver i find the .inf file.

I download the driver from Lenovo support website, should i download it from the official website or what is the problem? p.S i have a Broadcom chipset.

This is my configuration: Ubuntu 64-bit, Lenovo g510 i7

**This is my network Card Detail:  Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)**

Comment: If you can use the drivers that came with the wireless card it would be better. The .inf file is the hardware information (firmware) and if you can't extract it, you can try and find it online.

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device from the terminal command: lspci -nn | grep 0280 Thanks.

Comment: Please refrain from asking similar questions simultaneously. http://askubuntu.com/questions/540585/download-speed-limited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are running Ubuntu 14.04 or later, I suggest you get a temporary internet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Reboot and your wireless should be working.

Comment: i typed your command but this is the error that i get:

sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.

Comment: I would do: sudo apt-get update and then: sudo dpkg --configure -a Thanks.

Comment: i really want to cry of happiness! i was looking for solution since The previous friday, Thank you thank you